# how to remove characters from NSString after specific NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am having a string as follows

```
NSString str1 = @"Hello your bal = 68094";
```

and I want to remove all characters after **"="** symbol  encounters in string.

Can any one give me the solution for this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
NSString *str1 = @"Hello your bal = 68094";
NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@"="];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *newString = [str1 substringToIndex:range.location];
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
} else {
    NSLog(@"= is not found");
}
```

or

```
NSString *str1 = @"Hello your bal = 68094";
NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@"="];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *newString = [str1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
} else {
    NSLog(@"= is not found");
}
```

Update for @geekay_gk:
If you are sure that you would have 2 "=" in your string, then

```
NSString *str1=@"Hello your balance = 60094 and your id = rt456";
NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@"=" options: NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *newString = [str1 substringFromIndex:(range.location+1)];
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

If it contains whitespace, it would be better to trim the string.

Comment: Is there a way if the string was `Hello your balance = 60094 and your id = rt456` hw can I fetch rt456 now

Comment: @Ilanchezhian if there is no = means it will crash ,how check the condition

Comment: @KishoreKumar I have updated my first piece of snippets to handle the case. We can use similar condition to check whether it contains the specified character.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe not the best solution, but here it is:

```
NSString *str1=@"Hello your bal = 68094";
NSArray *tempArray = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
str1 = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", str1);
```

Output:

```
2012-03-15 11:21:01.249 TestApp[1539:207] Hello your bal
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thnx it works  however is there any method to directly trim after specific substring

Comment: @user968597 Check Aadhira's answer for that.