# delete a word that start with a symbol from a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to delete a word that start with a symbol from a string.

```
NSSting *string =@"Hello #world #ok";
```

I am trying to delete the word `"#world"` and `"#ok"` from this string because it they start with  a # 
so my string now should look like this

```
"Hello"
```

Comment: Yesmine have you satisfied with the below answers?

Comment: Or else do you want any other very simple solution?

Answer (score 3):

First Split your String in Array

```
 NSArray* arr = [@"Hello #world #ok" componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
```

Then Check the Occurence of `#`.

```
 NSString *myString;

 for(NSString *str in arr)
  {
    if(![str hasPrefix:@"#"])
      {  myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",myString,str];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why not use `NSMutableString` instead of creating umteen auto-release `NSString` objects?

Comment: You could use `hasPrefix:` to check for the "#" without creating the additional NSString each time.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw thanks For you Suggestion. I have no idea about `hasPrefix:` . Thanks for showing new way. I will update my answer in a while.

Answer (score 2):

1.Split string using spaces:

```
NSArray* splitArr = [@"Hello #world #ok" componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
```

2.Delete strings containing "#" & creating new string

```
NSMutableString* finalStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(NSString* str in splitArr) {
    if(![str hasPrefix:@"#"])
         [finalStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",str]];
}
```

The finalStr will be your desired string.

Comment: I've edited your `containsString:` to be `hasPrefix:`, as OP is looking for words **starting** with "#" to be removed, not words with "#" anywhere in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *str1 = @"Hello your bal = 68094";
NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@"="];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
  NSString *newString = [str1 substringToIndex:range.location];
  NSLog(@"%@",newString);
} else {
  NSLog(@"= is not found");
}
```

Comment: This is from @Ilanchezhian answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717723/how-to-remove-characters-from-nsstring-after-specific-nsstring

Answer (score 0):

May be below code can help:

```
    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"] invertedSet];;

    NSString *string =@"Hello #world #ok";

    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];

    for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {

        if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {

            string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[arr objectAtIndex:i] withString:@""];
        }
    }


    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                               [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

OR :

```
//add character in set to remove word with that character
    NSCharacterSet * set =[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"];

    NSString *string =@"Hello #world #ok";

    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];

    for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {

        if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {

            string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[arr objectAtIndex:i] withString:@""];
        }
    }


    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                               [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
NSArray* splitArr = [@"Hello #world #ok" componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
```

Step 2:

```
NSString *myString = @"";
for(NSString *str in splitArr)
{
  NSString *firstLetter = [str substringToIndex:0];
  if(![firstLetter isEqualToString:@"#"])
  {  
     myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",myString,str];
  }
}
```